# How to use raw_input with regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

with `raw_input()` I need to enter '\t' to split one string. '\t' is regular expression. When provided through `raw_input()` python transforms `\t` to `'\\t'`, so I cannot split the string.

```
line = '01/09/2015\t02:00\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1150592'

INPUT_separator = raw_input("- Separating character = ")

x = pd.DataFrame(line.split(INPUT_separator )).transpose()
```

Comment: `str.split()` doesn't use regular expressions. But you can do `'foo\tbar'.split('\t')`, since `\t` is just a literal tab character. No need for regex.

Comment: `raw_input` takes input kind of like how raw strings work, `r'\t'` is just "backslash t" where as `"\t"` is the tab character.  typing `\t` into a `raw_input` treats it as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

`\t` is not interpreted as a tab by `raw_input()` hence decoding it would be necessary. But `re` treats the literal `\t` as a tab. Hence you can also use `re` for this.

```
import re

line = '01/09/2015      02:00   0       0       0       0       0       0       1150592'
INPUT_separator = raw_input("- Separating character = ")
print re.split(INPUT_separator,line)
```

Comment: Your answer was better before edit, you just need to explain that `/t` in raw_input is not interpreted as a tab but the literal backslash t which is what `re` inteprets as the tab.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, the problem was arising because of the raw_input() as suggested by the above answer. My understanding of raw_input() was wrong. Hence the edit.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, sure, I will add this. Thanks!

Comment: sorry about downvote, I was just thinking your answer was pretty good then you removed explanation and I was like "noo why??!" which is not a good reason to downvote, will retract as soon as it is edited and I can.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, it's fine man. I wasn't sure about the behaviour and this gave a clear understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the input `\t` as a literal tab, you have to decode the escaped string input.

```
INPUT_separator = raw_input('Separating character = ').decode('string_escape')
```